# Sharepoint BLOB Storage RBS filestream to a Fileserver?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql-server, remote-blob-storage, rbs, file-server

I am currently trying to enable Remote blob storage in the SharePoint 2010 environment running on windows server 2008 and the SQL server is 2008 R2 enterprise edition in a separate box. In addition to that i have a new file-server just to store all the BLOB files on it. (this is because we have many SharePoint environment running for different uses).

Does anyone knows how to enable RBSfilestreams to another server (in my case it will be to the file-server).

I tried adding the file-server path as a mapped network drive (R:), but got the following error

> Msg 5135, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
>   The path 'R:\Blobstore' cannot be used for FILESTREAM files. For information about supported paths, see SQL Server Books Online.
>   Msg 5009, Level 16, State 14, Line 2
>   One or more files listed in the statement could not be found or could not be initialized.

It would be really great if someone can help me solve this issue ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

Quote from [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg638709.aspx):
RBS includes a FILESTREAM provider that lets you use RBS to store BLOBs on an instance of SQL Server. If you want use RBS to store BLOBs in a different storage solution, you have to use a third party RBS provider developed for that storage solution

In other words: If you use FILESTREAM, you can store BLOBs only to a disk that appears as local hard disk in diskmanagement of Windows (hard disk, iSCSI disk or FibreChannel disk). If you want to use other protocols (FileShare, NFS, ...) you have to buy a 3rd party tool like AvePoint StorageManager or Metalogix StoragePoint.

You could also read my previous [Post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/146720/how-much-space-in-the-db-will-be-saved-by-using-rbs/146723#146723) to decide if you really want to externalize your BLOBs.

Answer (score 0):

SQL-Server seems not to accept remote paths for storing blob-files. However, doing that is not a good solution at all. You are creating a source for Problems (what if there is a Problem with the accessibity of the fileshare) and a performance-loss (getting the data from another remote Server requires another request, especially in your case it can be a bottleneck when multiple Server requests files). Also, SQL-Server sets specific permissions on the blob-path, in order to not allow anyone else but the Service to see the files (not even the admin).
I don´t see any reason why one should want to put all blob Storages on a single Server.