# Content Database with RBS - Maximum size?

Tags: 2013, sql-server, sql-server-2012, rbs

what is the maximum size limit for a sharepoint content database  when it configured with RBS .
i mean max limit for content database .mdf file and rbs san / nas folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No different than if you were not using RBS. RBS data 'counts' against database size.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#ContentDB

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has defined some usage scenarios and put recommended limits behind:

- 200GB for general usage scenarios
- 4TB for all usage scenarios
- No explicit limit for document archive scenarios

It is important to understand that the requirements increase, as DB-size increases.

Reference: [Software boundaries and limits for SharePoint - Content database limits](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/install/software-boundaries-and-limits#ContentDB)

RBS does not increase the storage limits of content databases. All limitations still apply to RBS-enabled content databases. RBS is intended to lower storage costs by allowing you to store large read-intensive BLOBs on less expensive drives. For example, if you have 150 GB of RBS data and you have a content database that is 70 GB, this still exceeds the recommended limits of 200GB for a general usage scenario.

Reference: [Deciding to use RBS in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/administration/rbs-planning)

[Do not implement RBS just to move around 200GB limitation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/146720/how-much-space-in-the-db-will-be-saved-by-using-rbs/146723#146723).